# How to convert date format yyyymmdd to yyyy/mm/dd in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried some conversions but seems like it's not working. My datatype is a `decimal`:

```
date_column
-----------
20140619
20160527
20150601
20131127
20170217
20171204
20160519
```

My SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date_column), 111) AS mydate
FROM
    my_table
```

Results

```
mydate
-------------
2014-06-19
2016-05-27
2015-06-01
2013-11-27
2017-02-17
2017-12-04
2016-05-19
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). You should be storing your dates in `date` columns - where they don't *have* a format.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  Whilst I appreciate choosing the right data types is obviously very sensible, there is no indication that this data *isn't* being stored for use in the correct format from this question.  Rather, this may relate to parsing out necessary data fields within a staging environment to ensure the values *are* in the correct format when loaded into Production.  Put simply, I do not think your comment is constructive in this instance.

Comment: @iamdave - you're right that we don't know the exact context here. All I'll add is I've seen a lot of questions on here where people either think `date` *has* a format or they think their data *should* be a string version of a date conforming to a particular format when it turns out that they're only doing that because that's the format they want to show to their application's users.

Answer (score 2):

You currently do this:

```
decimal -> varchar -> date
```

which is good, but you are still missing one more step:

```
decimal -> varchar -> date -> varchar (new format)
```

Thus, you need:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), date_column)), 111) as mydate
from my_table
```

---

(What you should *actually* do is to store the date as a `DATE` in the first place, but I am aware that this is not always an option for legacy databases.)

Comment: i agree, but the database was developed way back. i get this error......Explicit conversion from data type decimal to date is not allowed.

Comment: @MiehleketoMathebula: Then it looks like you lied to us. :-) In your question, you mention that your datatype is `varchar`, whereas the error message claims that the datatype is `decimal`. Please find out what your *real* data type is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of the below code, based on your preference.

POST SQL SERVER 2012

```
declare @testDate DATE;
SET @testDate = '20140619'

SELECT FORMAT ( @testDate, 'd', 'zh-cn' ), FORMAT( @testDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en-US' )
```

Prior to SQL SERVER 2012

```
declare @testDate DATE;
SET @testDate = '20140619'

SELECT REPLACE(CAST(CONVERT(date,'20140619',111) AS CHAR(10),'-','/')
SELECT convert(char(10),@testDate,111)
```

Comment: thanks, i get this error from your last statement ''Explicit conversion from data type decimal to date is not allowed.''

Answer (score 0):

Let me share some of the answers i got:

select format(cast(date_column as date),'yyyy/MM/dd')  as mydate
from my_table;

select convert(date,convert(varchar(10), date_column ), 111 ) as mydate
from my_table;

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/53a51068-b802-43e7-baa3-7510d56c5b63/how-to-convert-date-formart-yyyymmdd-to-yyyymmdd-in-sql-server-2008?forum=transactsql

Thank you